# OV-VERTIS SmartCard reader Android 5.1

Tags: android, smartcard-reader, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I have device (OV-VERTIS) - Kingo Root showed that name.

- My phone is rooted.
- USB Host checker tells - it is compatible
- OTG Checker tells - it is compatible

But when I connect USB pendrive or Smart Card reader - Android (5.1) doesn't see this device.

When I connect the same pendrive / smart card reader to another phone (Samsung galaxy S5) everything works fine.

Could someone tell me what is wrong?

Maybe I need to install some drivers? Other soft to enabled connection between android and smart card reader?

Comment: What do you mean with "Android does not see the device"? There are apps, listing all USB devices. Connect the reader via some USB OTG cable and use one of these apps to see, if is detected as USB device

Comment: I have OTG cable (it works on other device). I connect reader to this cable. App that shows connected devices - doesn't see reader. Moreover, the LED on reader does not blink after connecting the reader. When I connect reader to SAMSUG it blinks